# Python - is it possible to insert() into a list inside of a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python is it possible to insert a value inside a list that's inside a list?

for example:

```
    List = [['Name',[1, 4, 6]],
    ['Another Name', [1,2,5]]]
```

I've tried to use:

```
    List.insert([0][1], 'another value')
```

but it doesn't like that, is there another way to manipulate lists inside lists?

Comment: `List[0].insert(1, 'another value')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely possible:

```
>>> List = [['Name',[1, 4, 6]],
...     ['Another Name', [1,2,5]]]
>>> List[0].insert(1,"Another Value")
>>> List
[['Name', 'Another Value', [1, 4, 6]], ['Another Name', [1, 2, 5]]]
```

You just need to subscript the "outer" list to get a reference to the "inner" list that you want to insert into.

We could break the above code into the following steps:

```
inner = List[0]
inner.insert(1,'Another Value')
```

If that makes it more clear to you what I actually did there ...

Comment: Yes!! I didn't think of specifying the list in the 'prefix' of the statement. Thank you very much mgilson!